# Capitalize partial reference to a title? e.g. "...at the Summer Folk Festival. The Festival is..."

Tags: capitalization

Do you capitalize "Festival" in this case?

For example, "She had a great time at the Summer Folk Festival. This year, the **Festival** featured several amazing acts, such as...".
Or another example, "The Integrity Commission works hard. Members of the Commission are diligent in..."

It makes sense to capitalize it if you see it as a part of the title, i.e., e.g., if you see "Festival" as being short for  "Summer Folk Festival."

Is this a matter of preference? Is there a right/wrong way to do it? Someone corrected all my "festival"s to "Festival"s :P

Comment: Neither is right or wrong in that example. It's a matter of style - and the preferred style may differ between different 'versions' of English (e.g. British, American, etc.) and between different people, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As TD noted, capitalization is a matter of style, and as such, different people will differ on which style to use.  That said, when you're referring to the proper name of an entity, it's generally advisable to capitalize the components.  If you abbreviate your reference by using only part of a name, it's still a proper name.  In particular, you'll want to keep the capital letter if using lower-case will confuse your reader.  For instance, consider come promotional text from the [The Stratford Festival](http://www.visitstratford.ca/the-stratford-festival?gclid=CjwKEAjwsr-6BRCLvrj785rbhTsSJADjUxakEThxa87UbH-7ESCauPp5OxpHRF9Rdkhbjp1K32SmtRoCjOjw_wcB) in Stratford, Ontario:

> The **Stratford Festival** is, quite simply, Canada’s premier theatre
>   arts festival.
>
> Stretching from late April until early November, the **Festival**
>   invites you to immerse yourself in all things theatrical.

The second *Festival*, in the second sentence, reminds us that the dates apply to The Stratford Festival.  The last word in the first sentence, *festival*, is lower-case because it doesn't refer to TSF but to a class of arts programs.